# Abandon image cassetts for LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, splash-screen, launch

So I have a fairly old app, last time worked on before iPhone X(s) was released. Always used Launch Images Source instead of Launch Screen File as seen below.

[image]

I am now having issues launching on iPhone X, as the screen size is assumed from the LaunchImage and there is NO launch image currently provided for iPhone X(s) in the "LaunchImage" file of .xcassets folder.

What is the most straightforward way to abandon using cassets in use of the new "Launch Screen File"? I have already tried creating this and using it, but had no luck getting an `UIImageView` to resize an image with said screen sizes on devices.

Im really looking for a straightforward guide for creating a  LaunchImage.storyboard file that can adapt a launch screen image(full-sized image) to any device size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the most straightforward way to abandon using cassets in use of the new "Launch Screen File"?

Change the Launch Images Source pop-up menu to "Don't use asset catalogs".

[image]

Make a LaunchScreen.storyboard if there isn't one, and point Launch Screen File at it. Make sure your launch image storyboard uses autolayout and is designated as a launch screen.

[image]

Now configure your storyboard's view controller using autolayout so that it lays out correctly on all devices.

Comment: could you update to reflect having single UIImageView in LaunchScreen ViewController that adapts to all device screen sizes as well? Good answer

Comment: So even doing just that, the app is not correctly sized to say, the 8+. Perhaps my lack of knowledge is "what is the first item in LaunchImage ViewController that defines the screen size for all devices?". Launching on 8+ sim, the app size, once launch screen goes away, is only filling <1/2 of the screen.

Comment: @Chisx The minimum you probably want is an image view that is constrained to each edge of the superview. Add an image to the image view. Set the content mode to "scale aspect fill"

Comment: @Paulw11 I actually tried this once, thanks though, I will try again - thoroughly going through the steps to make sure I am not just missing something, will get back when I have a positive result.

Comment: "the app size, once launch screen goes away, is only filling <1/2 of the screen" Okay, but @Chisx, that is a _completely different question_. The launch screen is different from the app. That is the whole point of the launch screen; it goes away, leaving you with the app. It is up to you to design the launch screen and the app to look similar, so that when the launch screen goes away, it seems to fade _into_ the app in a seamless way. You asked how to make the launch screen, and I told you. You are now asking how to make the _app_ look a certain way; that's a separate question.

Comment: Basically, the view controller designed in the _launch screen_ storyboard and the view controller designed as the _initial view controller_ in the _main_ storyboard must be designed roughly _the same way_ as one another. That way, when the first one is dissolved into the second one, the transition looks good. Study any app on your iPhone to see how this is done.

Comment: @matt I think we're having slight miscommunication. The app is already at near release state and resembles the complexity of an app like Twitter. (and is social media). The launch images that were being used look like Twitter's launch screen, colored gradient with white icon in center. The image cassets that were on file were sized for every phone except the new iPhone X(s).

Comment: Without the correct X launch image, the X sim showed two large black bars on top and bottom of screen.(this is addressed in another SO question already). The problem seemed to be that no Launch image was provided for the X. The solution however, could(as desired) involve migrating to LaunchScreen.storyboard, of which, is completely glitched out at the moment because I cant seem to get a UIImageView to scale to any screen size.

Comment: The result of launching at the moment on any device results in the smallest iOS screen definition for the app size within the screen (probably iPhone 5 or 6), causing, on an 8+, the app to appear as if it fills 1/2 the screen. (The LaunchScreen.storyboard's inner UIImageView that I placed there is not filling with the screen size)